# What do these three sentences imply?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, past-perfect, pragmatics

What do the three sentences imply?

> 1) I thought I would never have been an engineer.
>
> 2) I thought I would never be an engineer.
>
> 3) I thought I will never be an engineer.

Does the first sentence imply that I am an engineer now?

I’m not sure what the second sentence implies. Could it imply that I’ve just become an engineer?

Does the third sentence imply that I’m not an engineer now?

Comment: (1) requires some changes and a special context, e.g. *I thought "if it hadn't been for that teacher, I would never have been an engineer"*. Then it means that you are an engineer now. (2) implies that you are an engineer, but not necessarily that you've just become one (depends on context). (3) needs quotation marks: *I thought "I will never be an engineer"*. This doesn't have any strong implication by itself (it could be followed just as well by *so I gave up* or *but then the job came up at Brunel & Co*.

Comment: what's the reason behind putting it in qutations mark? regarding the first sentence, in real life conversation, without the main clause, does native speakers still understand that I am an engineer now?

Comment: If it is indirect speech, it gets backshifted, so *will* becomes *would*. If you see *will*, it has not been backshifted, so it is / should be direct speech, and direct speech goes in quotation marks. The sentence does not make sense without *if it hadn't been for that teacher* - you need that or something like it.

Comment: That is a new topic; you should ask it as a new question.

Comment: I somewhat agree with the comments here, but with some qualifications. The sentences don't *imply* anything; those interpreting them are simply *inferring* something—and may, themselves, find them to be suggestive. (Only the author of the sentences can say what was *implied*.) Also, the sentences are ambiguous. Just because it's *possible* to interpret them one way, doesn't mean it's impossible to interpret them another way. None of them mean that the person speaking is *necessarily* or *definitely* an engineer currently.